# mootools click:relay not firing on ipad/iphone

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am just creating a click event with mootools as follows:

```
$$('body').addEvent('click:relay(div.smart-bg)', function(){

xxxxxxxxxxx

});
```

However, this doesn't seem to fire on an iPad (whereas other click events do fire). Is this something to do with the fact it is a dynamic element added and that I am using :relay?

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Ad.

Comment: Could you please provide a test case?
This ist working on an iPad: http://jsfiddle.net/EvBNQ/1/

Comment: Any reason why you are using `$$('body')`? There's no reason to traverse the DOM to find the lone body tag, especially when it is already available as `document.body`...!

Answer (score 2):

I've run into similar problems when I added a delegated click event on a `div`.

[This article from quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/click_event_del.html) may help:

> There must be a reason for this behaviour. I don’t know what that reason is, but currently I think that it’s a memory management problem. Apparently, making all elements on a page clickable demands too many resources, and the Apple engineers decided to disable it.

and...

> Fortunately it’s pretty easy to solve: you have to make the element clickable by giving it an onclick event handler of its very own. That handler can be empty; as long as it’s present it will make any element clickable.

Perhaps in your case...

```
$$('.smart-bg').each(function(el) {
    el.onclick = function() {};
});
```

Although of course, given that it is a delegated event, you'll have to be sure to recreate the onclick handler on each `.smart-bg` element you dynamically create.